# How can I log initialization of objects created by Blueprint (Aries) during container initialization in Karaf?

Tags: logging, osgi, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi, blueprint

After reading about this, I felt like I understood it and now I am left baffled. Here is what I expect and what I did:

I expect to log into Karaf, reload my bundle, and run `log:tail` and eventually see a log message like this:

```
13:28:47.265 INFO [Blueprint] You just created a class called: MyClass.
```

Technologies used:
- OSGI Container implemented by Apache Karaf
- Blueprint implemented by Aries

1. My OSGI bundle imports the pax logger from Karaf

   `org.slf4j.*; provider=paxlogging`

to my understanding, this means that a reference to to the singleton logger of Karaf will be provided at runtime to my application, which only uses an API.

2. My classes use the SLF4J interface, so the dependency `slf4j-api:slf4j-api:1.7.26` exists in my project.
3. A class exists

Class serves a model

```
public class MyClass {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
  public MyClass() {
    LOGGER.info("You just created a class called: {}", this);
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() { return "MyClass" };
}
```

I just followed the specifications for an OSGI LoggerFactory:

> Consumers of this API must not implement this type https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.log.html#org.osgi.service.log.LoggerFactory

4. Aries creates one:

Blueprint XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd">

<description>
    A sample Blueprint XML to demonstrate 
    the initialization procedure in the hopes of reproducing a problem.
</description>

<bean id="myclass1" class=com.stack.MyClass/>
</blueprint>
```

## Related

- [How handle different logging solutions in OSGi (Apache Felix)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882345/how-handle-different-logging-solutions-in-osgi-apache-felix)
- [Activating an OSGI LogListener before other services?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572970/activating-an-osgi-loglistener-before-other-services)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this figured out:

The SLF4J API compiled in the bundle is part of the story. The rest is provided in Karaf / Felix by `org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api`. This thing does stuff in the background:

1. Setups up its own singleton logger factories.
2. Immediately enables SLF4J API support and logs a message.
3. One of the singleton logger factories is what SLF4J API needs to create loggers, the [Slf4jLoggerFactory](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/blob/master/pax-logging-api/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/logging/slf4j/Slf4jLoggerFactory.java). It, which holds a static reference to the `PaxLoggingManager` object (`Slf4jLoggerFactory.setPaxLoggingManager(manager)`, where manager is `new OSGIPaxLoggingManager(bundleContext)`). The method `getLogger` within this singleton returns a `new Slf4jLogger(name, paxLogger)` object (where name is usually a class name and the paxLogger is either from a `FallbackLogFactory.createFallbackLog(FrameworkUtil.getBundle(Logger.class), name)` or `m_paxLogging.getLogger(name, Slf4jLogger.SLF4J_FQCN)`. [Slf4jLogger](https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.logging/blob/master/pax-logging-api/src/main/java/org/ops4j/pax/logging/slf4j/Slf4jLogger.java)

So, it is necessary to bind to this specific `Slf4jLoggerFactory` (implements `ILoggerFactory`) so that all of the classes in the bundle get the correct reference when they call `getLogger(class)`. The problem with Aries Blueprint, it seems, is that it lazily binds the SLF4J API to the implementation provided by `headers org.ops4j.pax.logging.pax-logging-api`. So, I followed Christian Schneider's advice and created a top-level reference in Blueprint that forced Blueprint to wait for the Pax Manager to be ready:

```
 <reference id="logService" interface="org.osgi.service.log.LogService" availability="mandatory" activation="eager"/>
```

Then the other top-level managers can depend on this by using `depends-on`:

```
<bean id="MyRegistry" class="com.foo.MyRegistry" scope="singleton" factory-method="getSingletonInstance" depends-on="logService">
```

Of course, I needed to add the following to my OSGI MANIFEST.MF

```
Import-Package:
org.slf4j;version="[1.7.0,2.0.0)",
org.osgi.service.log,
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need special handling to enable slf4j logging in karaf. 
Simply use logging in your java code like you did and let the maven bundle plugin create a package import for you (no special config required).

The link to the OSGi R7 log service spec is an upcoming standardisation for logging. Basically this specification allows to inject loggers as OSGi services. This is technically cleaner than what karaf (pax-logging in fact) does today. 
In karaf this spec is not yet implemented.

Comment: @Schneider I liked your comment here https://stackoverflow.com/q/28882345/1236128. I think you might have misread my question.  I have all that setup (except I use the Gradle biz.aQute.bnd plugin). Objects created early are not logged. I need to know how to solve that. My guess is that I need to query a service manager and get a reference to pax logging early on (not sure how to do that yet).

Comment: Ah .. it is about not missing log entries. You can inject the org.osgi.service.log.LogService into the blueprint context. Pax logging provides this service and it would make sure you code is only executed when pax logging is ready.

Comment: Appeciated, but the documentation states the LogService is deprecated in favor of the LoggerFactory or Loggers. https://osgi.org/specification/osgi.cmpn/7.0.0/service.log.html

Comment: You would only use the LogService as kind of a marker service to let your blueprint context wait for it to be ready. You would not use the LogService to log stuff. Pax logging is also implementing a few other interfaces but I gave you the logservice one as it has a spec behind it .. so you do not need to depend on a pax logging specific interface.

Comment: I seem to have run into the same problem again, albeit with an updated version of Karaf and friends. Is it correct in Gradle to have the dependency `compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:${slf4jApiVersion}"` or do I need an implementation somewhere? Logging is working for threads that get created later, but not the stuff created early on in the bootstrap phase of Aries Blueprint. Bundle imports `org.slf4j;version="[1.7,2)"`

Comment: The API should be good enough in the dependencies. If logging works for some threads then your dependencies are correct. If you do no see all logs then this might be a bug in pax logging.